# Triangle inequality in product space of normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be normed spaces, then $\|(x,y)\|:=(\|x\|_X^p+\|y\|_Y^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is a norm on $X \times Y$.

This is absolutely clear to me, but I have troubles to verify the triangle inequality for this norm. Does anybody know how to do this or have a good hint?

Comment: Have you tried using Hoelder's and Minkowski's inequalities?

Comment: I tried to use Minkowski's, but did not succeed. I do not see where to use Hoelder's.

Comment: Minkowski's inequality will give you the result directly. Hoelder's is used to prove Minkowski's.

Comment: so by Minkowski we get: $((||x_1||_X+||x_2||_X)^p + (||y_1||_Y+||y_2||_Y)^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and then?

Comment: Try proving Hoelder's inequality for the product space. Then use it to prove Minkowski's inequality. That is the triangle inequality.

Comment: According to my book, this should be possible much easier. sorry that I do not go in the direction you are suggesting, but I think it cannot be that hard

Comment: Proving Hoelder's and Minkowski's inequalities is not too tough. Try adapting the two proofs at the bottom of this page: http://faculty.unlv.edu/pushkin/mat707/inequalities.pdf

Comment: Should you find a simpler proof, I would like to see it, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \|(x+u,y+v)\| = (\|x+u\|_X^p + \|y+v\|_Y^p)^{1/p} 
\\ \le ((\|x\|_X+\|u\|_X)^p + (\|y\|_Y+\|v\|_Y)^p)^{1/p} 
\\ = \|(\|x\|_X,\|y\|_Y) + (\|u\|_X,\|v\|_Y)\|_{\ell^p} 
\\ \le \|(\|x\|_X,\|y\|_Y)\|_{\ell^p} + \| (\|u\|_X,\|v\|_Y)\|_{\ell^p}
\\ = (\|x\|_X^p+\|y\|_Y^p)^{1/p} + (\|u\|_X^p+\|v\|_Y^p\|)^{1/p} $$